# Customizing Android Webview class

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm writing an Android app (android 2.3.3 / API 10) where I'm loading websites via WebView. Looking at the android.webkit.webview source code, specifically onSavePassword(...) (you can find it [HERE](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView.onSavePassword%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.os.Message%29)) I would like to initiate my own custom AlertDialog instead of the stock one
and apply my changes, or do I have to edit the android.webkit.webview source and recompile the android.jar?

I should have explained earlier that I attempted something like this with no success:

```
class MyWebView extends WebView { 
    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
@Override
    boolean onSavePassword(String schemePlusHost, String username, String password, final Message resumeMsg) {
        boolean rVal = false;
           if (resumeMsg == null) {
               // null resumeMsg implies saving password silently

           } else {
                final Message remember = mPrivateHandler.obtainMessage(REMEMBER_PASSWORD);
                remember.getData().putString("host", schemePlusHost);
                remember.getData().putString("username", username);
                remember.getData().putString("password", password);
                remember.obj = resumeMsg;

                final Message neverRemember = mPrivateHandler.obtainMessage(NEVER_REMEMBER_PASSWORD);
                neverRemember.getData().putString("host", schemePlusHost);
                neverRemember.getData().putString("username", username);
                neverRemember.getData().putString("password", password);
                neverRemember.obj = resumeMsg;

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                        .setTitle("My Custom Title")
                        .setMessage("My Custom Save/Don't Save Dialog Message")
                        .setPositiveButton(com.android.internal.R.string.save_password_notnow,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                resumeMsg.sendToTarget();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNeutralButton(com.android.internal.R.string.save_password_remember,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                remember.sendToTarget();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(com.android.internal.R.string.save_password_never,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                neverRemember.sendToTarget();
                            }
                        })
                        .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                resumeMsg.sendToTarget();
                            }
                        }).show();
                // Return true so that WebViewCore will pause while the dialog is
                // up.
                rVal = true;
            }
           return rVal;
    }
```

Eclipse just claims "The method onSavePassword(String, String, String, Message) of type MainActivity.MyWebView must override a superclass method" and tells me to remove the @Override. And the changed dialog doesn't take.

Thanks Again

**EDIT**

The method I want to change ie. onSavePassword(...) in the android webview.class has no modifier associated with it. I think that means that this method is only accessible to classes that reside in the same package. Just as I mentioned before, I attempt to create my own webview class that extends the stock class, but it does not find onSavePassword. Any ideas, or examples of other extensions of the webView class that may point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Once you extended the `WebView` class with your own, you should just rename every webviews in your Layout XML files by `com.packagename.YourNewWebViewClass`.

in fact :

```
<WebView layout......></WebView>
```

Shall become

```
<com.mypackage.MyWebView layout....></com.mypackage.MyWebView layout>
```

That should do the trick !

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having trouble with the webView extension class. Is there some example code where someone were able to successfully extend webview?

Answer (score 0):

Just override.

But you should adopt a strategy of try-test-error cycle, it's a goog way to learn in IT...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just tried performing the @Override like this:  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{}

Comment: Overriding is not subclassing.. Overiding means to redefine a method, in a subclass, that has been inherited from a sueprclass.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make your own `WebViewExt` class that extends `WebView` and override the function? Then use your own `WebViewExt` and forget `WebView` exists.

Comment: That sounds like the solution I would like to follow. I've found the method I would like to override: /* package */ boolean onSavePassword(String schemePlusHost, String username,
            String password, final Message resumeMsg) but when I make the changes in MyWebView class, I get "The method onSavePassword(String, String, String, Message) of type MyWebView must override a superclass method". Any example code out there from sombody else who's building their own webview class?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a same package as WebView in your code and put your class in that package. at runtime it will be considered to be in the same package and you will be able to use @override annotation

Comment: Thanks for the post. That was the direction I was leaning towards but I never got it to work. Have an example?