# Allowing only a particular protocol to view webpage

Tags: php, android, .htaccess, webserver

I was developing an android application and I was wondering if there is anyway to prevent or make it harder for users to view a particular web page.

E.g. my application goes to mysite.com/info.php, this info.php displays the URL and data of the location of my videos.

I wish to prevent users from obtaining this URL and getting the videos other than by the android application. Is there anyway to do this?

I've thought of using a .htaccess file and a user/pass but realized that it would be possible for someone to sniff the user and pass from outgoing connections.

I wonder if anyone has the solution for this?

Comment: Move the files out of the web root and server them with a small script that checks entitlement first.

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by checks entitlement??

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading web pages in an app (and not from a browser) then extend WebView like this:

[Android Webview loading other URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696213/android-webview-loading-other-urls?rq=1)

in the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method you can filter whatever you like - based on server, directories, pages, etc.

.htaccess mods require rooted access or Android mods (like cyanogenmod). Also, you can customize the web experience in the webview. Here are the basics:

[Customizing Android Webview class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317702/customizing-android-webview-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep tokens with the limited time of validity and add hash of token concatenized with "secret" key to each query of your Android application to your site.

For example, you can create a small script on the server which will generate tokens with limited validity time:

gettoken.php:

```
 <?php

 $token = date("YmdH");

 echo $token;

 ?>
```

Then, to make query to your site, your Android application should get this token and make a hash from token, concatenized with "secret" string.

If you could use php for this, this could be looks as this:

```
 <?php

 $token = file_get_contents("http://yoursite/gettoken.php");
 $secret = "secretkey";
 $hash = md5($token.$secret);

 $content = file_get_contents("http://yoursite/&hash=".$hash);

 /// use $content contains a page of your site

 ?>
```

And your site should check the hash this way:

```
 <?php

 if(!isset($_REQUEST['hash']))
   die();

 $token = date("YmdH");
 $hash = $_REQUEST['hash'];
 $secret = "secretkey";

 if(md5($token.$secret)!=$hash)
   die();


 /// .... your content here


 ?>
```

In this example, token will be changed each hour, so if someone sniffs the hash, it will be valid no more than one hour.